# Iseries SQL DBU Flatten Row into Columns

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange, flatten

I have an iSeries server running V5R4. I need to flatten a row into columns. Here's an example of the data:

```
Sequence    Ordn        Ordl    Percentage
1           0140766       1          0
2           0140766       1         30
3           0140766       1          7
4           0140766       1          3 
1           0140766       2          0
2           0140766       2         30
3           0140766       2          2
```

Sequence is the order in which the percentages should be calculated
Ordn is the customer's order number
Ordl is the order line number
Percentage is a list of percentages off list price

The number of rows (or percentages) can vary from 1 - 5 for any given order line.

The file would need to be grouped on order number and sorted first on order line number and then sequence.

I need to flatten this file so that it displays in the following way:

```
Ordn    Ordl    Perc1   Perc2   Perc3   Perc4   Perc5
0140766   1       0       30      7       3      Null
0140766   2       0       30      2      Null    Null
```

Can anyone help? I have tried several things but nothing works the way I want and my SQL experience is very limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to manually pivot the data into five sequence columns.  It assumes there are only five possible sequences.  Also, if you have more than one row with a given sequence, the percentages will be added together.

```
select                                                            
  ordn                                                            
, ordl                                                            
, sum(case when sequence=1 then percentage else null end) as perc1
, sum(case when sequence=2 then percentage else null end) as perc2
, sum(case when sequence=3 then percentage else null end) as perc3
, sum(case when sequence=4 then percentage else null end) as perc4
, sum(case when sequence=5 then percentage else null end) as perc5
from yourtable                                              
group by ordn, ordl                                               
order by ordn, ordl
```

(Note that the `else null` clauses are not strictly necessary here, since `null` is the default value of a `case` expression that lacks an `else` case.)